# Selenium/Node.js/Heroku combination no error displayed, but scraping function doesn't print anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku

So I've already added the required build packs to my Heroku app. My app.js file has the correct imports (I believe) and I thought I was implementing the function correctly, but I guess I'm not. FYI, I'm calling the scraping function every minute using a cron schedule function.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
require('chromedriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
let options = new chrome.Options();
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

function scrape() {
    let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
      .forBrowser('chrome')
      .setChromeOptions(options)
      .build();
    driver.get('https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/');
    let elements = driver.findElements(By.css('p'));
    for(let e of elements) {
        console.log(e.getText());
    }
    driver.quit();
};
```

and in my cron function I just call

```
scrape()
```

Cron runs a couple times and then I get this weird error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6t0U.jpg